# Upload single image with MySQL query

Tags: mysql, upload, photo

Good day!

I have a task in our company portal that deals with uploading/ editing of profile picture. Furthermore, inline with the uploadify, I have to deal with some MySQL queries because I have to insert the data such as the name of the photo, type of user who uploaded it, date and time of upload, etc., to our database and/or update it whenever it is being edited.

Could someone please help me. I need an someone now to save me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

A photo, or a file in general, can be saved into a database in a BLOB field.
A BLOB is (very easy description) is a byte array, so using any language you can use a query like `INSERT INTO my_table (id, descr, image) SELECT (NULL, 'my_descr', my_image)` where my_image can be passed as parameter while parameter value is byte[].
In C# you do this reading file with `byte[] my_image = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);` but in any language you can do that.
Remember to define a BLOB field in db, use a parameter in your query and pass a byte[] to that param to insert file into db.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<input type="file"/>` input tag in a `<form/>` with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` atttribute value and `$_FILES` super global to get uploaded file's content and meta.  Use PDO or Mysqli to INSERT/UPDATE information into database.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good explanation in PHP:
http://www.phpriot.com/articles/images-in-mysql

Long story short: (1) you have to create a blob field, (2) get the file contents as a byte array and (3) insert the row using the created array.